# HTTP request failed, statusCode: 403,tile.openstreetmap.org in Flutter

Tags: flutter, openstreetmap, fluttermap

Am getting the 403 error while trying to load tiles from the OpenStreetMap, I am looking for a way to solve the issue, I think I might have violated the heavy use but the app is just in the development stage.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is happening, if a proper User-Agent is not set to access open street map.

For Android:
Please put this in your activity before loading the map.
OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants.setUserAgentValue(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);

But for flutter, do you use any plugins? for example : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_osm_plugin

Please provide some more details on how you are accessing osm from your flutter app.

Comment: Apart from flutter_map plugin I dont use any other map plugin?.
When I add "OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants.setUserAgentValue(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);"
on my dart file that I load the map I get an error